# mysite masterpage check if its current users mysite

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, mysite

I try to add a link to users mysite only if the current user is on his mysite (Or on mysite host).

Is there a solution to add something on the masterpage to check this in .Net? I googled a lot but didn't find anything to achieve this directly on masterpage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript API to retrieve current User MySite URL and then compare  and show or hide link based on that

```
$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties?$select=UserUrl",
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },
    success: function (data) {
        var userUrl = data.d.UserUrl;
        alert(userUrl);         
    },
    error: function (err) {
        alert("Request Failed");
    }
});
```

Comment: if Javascript is an Option, you could do it simply by the values of _spPageContextInfo Object

webTemplate gives you Information of the template, the current web is originated (eg 21 is personal site, 54 is for mysiteHost, 1 is for Teamsite)

webTitle uses the DisplayName of the user, the current MySite belongs to

siteServerRelativeUrl consists of the subsite for personal Sites and the accountName of the user the currentMySite belongs to (eg /personal/pexlel)

Answer (score 0):

you have to build your own control and place it on the masterpage either directoy or via delegate control

You are not able to execute code directly in the masterpage